# Authentication issue on Integrating OneDrive iOS sdk

Tags: ios, github, sdk, onedrive

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-ios) to integrate the OneDrive sdk into my project. 
Followed the steps as mentioned in the doc,

1. Installation (Done)
2. Getting started

   2.1 Register your application (Done)

   2.2 Set up Keychain Sharing Entitlements in your Xcode Project (Done)

   2.3 Getting an authenticated ODClient object (**Authentication Failed**)

Since my application is targeting OneDrive for Business. This is how my call looks like,

```
[ODClient setActiveDirectoryAppId:"ONE_DRIVE_BUSINESS_CLIENT_ID" redirectURL:@"REDIRECT_URI"]];
```

I get this error

> Error with code: 15 Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:access_denied Details:AADSTS65005: The application 'xxx' required resource access list does not contain applications discoverable by 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'.
>   Trace ID: xxx
>   Correlation ID: xxx
>   Inner error details: 
>   Error Domain=ADAuthenticationErrorDomain Code=15 "(null)"

on requesting ODClient,

> `[ODClient clientWithCompletion:^(ODClient *client, NSError *error){  }];`

I tried removing the authentication from the redirect url, but still getting the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.